# Apply free shipping coupon code only for spefic shipping method

Tags: magento2, coupon-codes

in project i have two different custom shipping method one for **8 to 15 days** delivery and **2 to 4 days** delivery.
i have create coupon code for free shipping but i want to **allow** free shipping coupon code to only  **8 to 15 days** shipping method.
please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change code in your carrier model file  collectRates function check coupon code is applied or not from calling quote object and set custom price if your 8 to 15 days delivery method available and set 0 price for free shipping .

**you can get a coupon code from quote object from here**

```
$quote  = $this->session->getQuote();

$address = $quote->getShippingAddress();

$shippingaddress    = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getData();

$coupon     = $quote->getCouponCode();
```

**Before apply this code you have to declare session in construct method like this**

```
protected $session;

public function __construct(

\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session, ) {   

$this->session = $session;

}
```

after then you get quote data from session in magento 2.

Answer (score 2):

Magento Provide Shipping Method condition it self,

You need to select that shipping method into condition section, For which you want to generate coupen code.

See the screen-sort.
[image]

Comment: this will not work for me bcz i am using table rate shipping method and i have create module for custom table rate shipping method

Comment: you can change your custom module development, So that method avilable into this list, so you can select that.

Comment: ok i am trying that one

Comment: Above answer help please accept, so other can get help in community.